# Android call View Controller method from ViewModel

Tags: android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I started playing around with Android JetPack (ViewModel, Architecture Components, LIfeCycle and so on).
Untill now, I was working with Model View Presenter architecture, and actually I found it a quite easy to test and maintain architecture.

On the other hand, The big advantage I can see by using ViewModels instead, is their native coupling with Activities and Fragments lifecycle, which always was one of the biggest pains for Android developer, so I think this is a very big step forward.

Said that, I think there is a big disavantage though: with this new approach, it seems much more tricky to call Activity's or Fragment's methods, because, as stated in the official docs

> A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that
>   may hold a reference to the activity context.

In MVP approach, the Presenter had a contract with the view and could call all of its methods. I made some research on how to address this scenario with Architecture components, but it seem there is no easy and painless way to do that: at the end you always have to handle states in ViewModel and react to these  changes in Activities and Fragments. Someone suggest to use [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) class, which makes it a little bit easier, but still much more painfull than before.

So my question is:

The docs say you cannot reference anything holding a reference to an Activity Context (to avoid memory leaks I guess), but what if I do that and then I clear all references in ViewModel's onCleared()?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't avoid memory leaks, because for example if you rotate your device your `activity` will be destroyed, then recreated, but the `VM` would remain the same, and it's `onCleared` would not be called (hence your old activity still remains in memory, since your `VM` still references it).

Generally the MVVM conceptually says, that the `ViewModels` should not know about the `View` and this is the beauty of **architecture**: there is not a better *pattern*, just a more *suitable* one, and you should choose the one, that works better for you.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of couple of ways to "notify a user" of the `ViewModel`:

1. A `LiveData` object that changes and an `Observer` to this data
2. Send a `Broadcast` to a `BroadcastReceiver` using the Application's `Context`, if you don't mind [accessing it statically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/4759619) from the `ViewModel`

**Edit:** I know this is not exactly an answer to the question, but I think it removed the need for it

Answer (score 0):

> but what if I do that and then I clear all references in ViewModel's onCleared()?

That is far too late. `onCleared()` is only called if the Activity is finished / the Fragment is removed, it is not called on configuration changes.

---

But you could potentially use some form of command queue to emit events only when a subscriber is available, for example [`DispatchWorkSubject`](https://akarnokd.github.io/RxJava2Extensions/javadoc/hu/akarnokd/rxjava2/subjects/DispatchWorkSubject.html) in  [RxJava2-Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions).

Just make sure you make your subscriptions in `onStart` and then dispose your disposable in `onStop`.